# Error downloading on Windows 8

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

[image]

We are unable to fully install the program - see error below.

Comment: "The operation could not be completed for the following reason: The operation failed for some reason." Well... duh.

Comment: Maybe try to install it as an administrator? Or try to change the setting on compatibility tab and set it to "Windows 7"? Just a suggestion.

Comment: I also have the very same problem. Online suggestions included uninstalling various Adobe programs or readers. Have tried this without success. Notice that there is a slash in the wrong direction in the error message: "...miktex/bin..." I am wondering if there is a typo in the installation program that trips up the process.